# Operational amplifier with reverse diode

Tags: amplifier

On the first picture is a simple schematic. For example, we can get the transfer function simply by equaling
"ud+u2" and "Ad*(u1-u2)".
The transfer function is: u2 = (Ad*u1)/(1+Ad) - ud/(1+Ad)

[image: Picture 1]

On the next picture, that diode is turned in other direction.
I am not sure how can I get transfer function. My logical explanation (which is probably wrong) is that the diode does not conduct any electricity, so the current there is zero.

[image]

I am asking for the explanation, when and why do we have a voltage on u2 (on the last picture).

Comment: The circuit which you have shown is a superdiode, also called precision rectifier, and is used to rectify signals whose magnitude is smaller than the threshold of the diode ( 0.7 for Si, 0.3 for Ge) itself. This might help :    http://ecetutorials.com/analog-electronics/precision-diode-op-amp-half-wave-rectifier/ .

Answer (score 1):

The schematic corresponds to a [Precision Rectifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier). This type of circuit is used as a half-wave rectifier signals whose amplitude is less than the threshold voltage of the diode.
The connection with an operational amplifier, linearizes transfer curve for a diode, making it more ideal. This allows rectify signals from virtually zero.

The diagrams that you have posted, corresponding to *half-wave rectifiers*. An *improved implementation* of a precision rectifier is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzsH8I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For a **full-wave recitifier**, the  assembly is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbQdRf.png)</sup>

If this circuit you invert the connection of the diodes, you get the output pulses with positive polarity. In the circuit shown, the polarity of the pulse is negative.

[Here](http://diodes.com/_files/products_appnote_pdfs/zetex/an55.pdf), you can view a CI that implements a precision rectifier in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, there should be some load resistor shown to compute gain but even with that when the diode is reversed the OP Amp becomes open-loop and saturates, so neither are practical.

The improved design is as follows.

[image]